# Safari doesn't open .pkpass wallet pass

Tags: ios, aws-lambda, safari, aws-api-gateway, passkit

I have read all similar issues posted on PassKit and pass download issues with Safari.

Tried mime to Apple pass type in header from handler lambda.
My case might be a bit different.

Have a create_pass lambda handler function hosted behind API Gateway.

Set binary encoding to true.
Binary type to */* in API GW.

Iam able to download .pkpass file in windows and android. The link downloads first when clicked on downloaded file opens in Passes App in android.

Using the same download link throws errors on IOS with Chrome and Safari.

Has anyone had same errors?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

The generated pass wasnt working, think Safari is trying to preview and it fails.
Tried with a diffrent pass certifate and key and it worked.